# Tomcat7 OpenShift How to put jar to app-root/data?

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, jar, openshift

I have web app. I use Git plugin in NetBeans to deploy the app to **OpenShift**. Now I have to add ([according to this](http://kornicameister.blogspot.com.by/2013/04/jdbc-realm-tomcat7-and-openshift.html)) JDBC connector to **app-root/data** in **OpenShift** filesystem. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I've found out it is not possible just to copy/move/add/put `JAR` to `app-root/data`. But you can download it from the internet.

1. start your `rhc` client (start command line under `c:\Users\YourUserName\`) then print commands:
2. make connection to your app

   `c:\Users\YourUserName\rhc ssh --ssh  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -a yourApp`

or `c:\Users\YourUserName\rhc ssh --ssh C:\Progra~1\Git\usr\bin\ssh.exe -a yourApp`
Depends on where your `ssh.exe`

3. then `cd $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR`
4. then `wget http://someFileHosting/fileName`
5. after it's done check the list with `ls`